# How to define a custom Text.Comparator

Tags: hadoop

My mapper will emit the <*Text*, *Text*> to the reducer, and the key is actually the double, for example, <'34.90', 'hello'>, means the average count of 'hello' is 34.90. Besides, the input format is: hello 34.90 fiction1:10;fiction2:20;...,
it seems that I can't use the InverseMapper.

I tried use 'DoubleWritable' as the key, but I don't know how to emit it, the Collect seems emit the <*Text*, *Text*> only.

And the question is that '929.00' is smaller than '93.00', against the truth, so I want to define a new Text.Comparator, I see the source code

```
public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2)
{
  int n1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]);
  int n2 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]);
  return compareBytes(b1, s1 + n1, l1 - n1, b2, s2 + n2, l2 - n2);
}
```

I don't understand `s1+n1` and `l1-n1` meaning.

Thank you for your help ^_^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `FloatWritable`. Here is how you can emit that in mapper.

```
public class CheckMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,FloatWritable,Text> 
{
//calculation on your hello count
public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
float var = hello_count;
String otheroutput = //do something with value
context.write(new FloatWritable(var),new Text(otheroutput));
}
}
```

You don't need to define a custom comparator class here, inbuilt functionality of FloatWritable will take care of that.

Comment: Thank you, it's resolved. And I do understand how to emit the doubleWritable, I miss this point:Mapper<LongWritable, Text, <here>FloatWritable<\here>, Text>

Comment: If it resolved your question please accept the answer.